# Someone calls or someone call

Tags: plural-forms, singular, indefinite-pronouns

I read that someone is used with singular verb but l come across with this example :

> Someone call an ambulance.

Is it correct? It shouldn't be "someone calls an ambulance"?!

Or in another example:

> I need something to hold this window open.

Shouldn't it be holds ? Like:

I need something to holds this window open.

Comment: It depends on the context. This is an imperative: "Someone – call an ambulance!" And this is a statement in the continuous present: "Someone calls an ambulance". In the second example, "I need something to holds this window open" is grammatically wrong, but OTOH "I need something **that** holds this window open" would work.

Comment: Asked on ELU: [What is the grammatical mood of the sentence "Someone stop that person"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613207/191178)

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/56820/weather-vane could you please tell me why "holds" in my second example wrong? ,I want to know more, so l stop doing the same mistake again.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/56820/weather-vane to holds is wrong because it's an infinitive, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 2 examples could both be correct depending on context.
**Someone call an ambulance** is a request that an ambulance be called by someone.
**someone calls an ambulance** is an observation (or possibly stage direction) that an ambulance is called.
**I need something to hold this window open.** Is perfectly correct English stating a need, whilst **I need something to holds this window open** is just plain wrong.